# Peformanace issue on setting RaiseListChangedEvent property multiple times

Tags: refresh, bindingsource, performance-testing, listchanged

Before refreshing a control I'm setting the RaiseListChangedEvent property of its bindingsource to false then after the refresh I'll set it again to true and set ResetBindings to false.

What if the scenario will be like this:

```
set RaiseListChangedEvent = false in 100 times 

then

set RaiseListChangedEvent = true in 100 times

set ResetBindings(false)
```

Will it cause any performance issue?

Comment: please advice if you have idea on scenario above. thanks